Can I read the SLES registration key from a backup?
When trying to upgrade a PC from SLES12 SP5 to SLES15 SP6, the upgrade just stopped after 400 packets or so (with over 1200 packets to be done).
When trying a new installation instead (the PC being unusable), I need the registration key that I did not write down, but I had made a backup.
So the question is: Is there some file on the local system (so that I can restore it from backup) telling me what the SLES registration code is?

You can view the registration key at SUSE Customer Center: https://scc.suse.com/home .
To see your "Registration code", you login into SCC, click your organization under "MY ORGANIZATIONS" on the left side, then select "Subscriptions" top mid, then select the correct subscription (example: "SUSE Linux Enterprise Server..."), then you can find the registration code in red color under tab "Subscription Information". Make sure your subscription is not expired. (You also can show expired subscriptions.)
To see your "Mirroring credentials", you login into SCC, click your organization under "MY ORGANIZATIONS" on the left side, then select "Users" top mid, then select "Organization Credentials". Those can be used for SMT, RMT and SUSE Manager.
If you want to register a usual system, just open yast via console and select "Software", then "Product Registration" and choose registration via email. You need to use the same email as of your SUSE SCC account.

Alternatively, you may find the "key" files in directory /etc/zypp/credentials.d/, they can be opened using a text editor - but these seem to be encrypted.
I've not tested it, but if you want to "transplant" the old key files to a new system, you need first to use the same OS version and then copy following files from the old to the new system:
/etc/SUSEConnect
/etc/zypp/credentials.d/*
/etc/zypp/repos.d/*
/etc/zypp/services.d/*
/etc/machine-id

Maybe /etc/machine-id is not needed.
A problem could be, that your old system might have contacted the registration server - while setup - and told it to change the registered OS version to the newer one. If so, the old registration won't work anymore. Usually you need to register it new. But then you need to login into SUSE Customer Center anyway and delete the wrongly registered system.

The files inside credentials.d contain username and password, sometimes also a system_token. But most notable the password is not the registration code. Before asking the question I had traced SUSEConnect --status that outputs the registration code for a running system, but it seems it involves some gpg operation working in a temporary setup directory.

And in the "Systems" tab of SCC I cannot see the registration codes used; in "Subscriptions" I can see registration codes, and from there under "Details" I can see the machines registered to use that registration code...

I've updated my answer @U.Windl

I think the username and password data found in the credentials directory are not encrypted; instead they simply don't show the registration code. The gpg process I had mentioned gets it' data from stdin, and it's not obvious what kind of data it is (I didn't go that deeply into tracing).
